# Google sheets Calculating Milage Based on Lat/Long or Address

Tags: google-maps, google-sheets

Yes, I have converted the lat/long to decimal and the cell format is set to number.

My expectation is to be able to use an address as the origin and an address **OR** lat/long for the destination and get the distance using the Google Maps API. Like I said, it works with address to address.

The code below is to calculate the mileage from an address to an address OR lat/long using Google Maps. The API is enabled and **the code works for address to address**, but when I try to do address to lat/long, or lat/long to lat/long I get the error:

> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'legs') (line 7)."

```
function getDistance(origin, destination) {
  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setOrigin(origin)
    .setDestination(destination)
    .getDirections();

  var distance = directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;

  return distance;
}

function getDistanceFromLatLon(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2) {
  var origin = lat1 + "," + lon1;
  var destination = lat2 + "," + lon2;

  var directions = Maps.newDirectionFinder()
    .setOrigin(origin)
    .setDestination(destination)
    .getDirections();

  var distance = directions.routes[0].legs[0].distance.text;

  return distance;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So, the issue is that the Lat was in one cell and the Long was in another. It needs to be in a single cell i.e. 42.0811, -91.2594